# How to find class name of ExecutableElement?

Tags: java, annotation-processing

I'm writing an annotation processor which i use `PostConstruct` annotation only for methods. Assume that i have a class like this:

```
public MyClass{

   @PostConstruct
   public void onCreate(){

   }
}
```

So inside my annotation processor i can get `onCreate` method:

```
   for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(PostConstruct.class)) {

            if (element.getKind() != ElementKind.METHOD) {
                return false;
            }
            ExecutableElement method = (ExecutableElement) element;

        }
```

And also i need to know about the class name of `onCreate` method (`MyClass`) but `ExecutableElement` didn't provide any methods to do that. Is there any other utility classes to give me the class name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class declaring a method is the method's enclosing element:

```
TypeElement declaringClass =
    (TypeElement) method.getEnclosingElement();

String className =
//            also getSimpleName()
    declaringClass.getQualifiedName().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

When casting gets involved, it usually means one of the visitor API should be used instead. While they are more verbose, they are the only safe option.

The following example triggers a compilation error if something else than a type element is visited, you can obviously adapt that part to your need.

```
public class TypeElementVisitor extends SimpleElementVisitor8<TypeElement, Void>
{
    private final Messager messager;

    public TypeElementVisitor( Messager messager )
    {
        this.messager = messager;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeElement visitType( TypeElement e, Void ignored )
    {
        return e;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeElement visitUnknown( Element e, Void ignored )
    {
        messager.printMessage( Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Expected an enclosing class, got: " + e.toString(), e );
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
ExecutableElement execElement = [...];
ElementVisitor<TypeElement, Void> enclosingTypeVisitor = new TypeElementVisitor( processingEnvironment.getMessager() );
TypeElement enclosingType = enclosingTypeVisitor.visit( execElement.getEnclosingElement() )
```